# Beginner Python - Why the nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested

I am creating a new column and appending a dataframe and have created a function for the new column:

```
def male_female_child(passenger):
    age, sex = passenger

    if age < 16:
        return 'child'
    else:
        return sex
```

My question is about the line of code that executes the function:

```
titanic_df['person'] = titanic_df[['Age','Sex']].apply(male_female_child, axis = 1)
```

Why is `titanic_df[['Age','Sex']]` a nested list? I guess I'm wondering why `titanic_df['Age','Sex']` wouldn't work? Also, why is argument `axis = 1` given?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what `titanic_df` is for us?

Comment: I agree with @bmhkim, the structure of `titanic_df` is missing in the provided code, thus, hard to give a specific answer. Based on the **limited provided code**, the `axis = 1` appears meaningless/useless, at first glance. This could be clarified better if you included the code for `apply`. If I am reading this correctly, the [['Age,'Sex']] is to specify a list within `titanic_df` for proper referencing [...] is the list; however, `titanic_df[...]` is a parent element, therefore, the double [[]].

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to python! :)

First you should study up on list methods, specifically the subscript notation that lets you refer to indexes and slices of a given list.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Now, you're using pandas, right? `titanic_df[['Age','Sex']]` is not a nested list, it's a subscript call on the object `titanic_df`, which isn't a list but a pandas.DataFrame. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

A pandas DataFrame has methods that allow you to refer only to specified columns or rows, using similar subscript notation. The differences between DataFrame subscript notation and standard list subscript notation are that

1. with a DataFrame, you can index or slice in 2 dimensions, rows and columns, e.g. `titanic_df[columns][rows]`
2. you can pass a list or tuple of non-contiguous column or row names or indices to operate on, e.g. not just `titanic_df[1][1]` (second row, second column) or `titanic_df['Age'][1]` (Age column, first row) but `titanic[

The subscript can be specified as any of:

1. an integer (representing the index of a single column you wish to operate on)
2. a string (representing the name of a single column you wish to operate on)
3. A list or tuple of integers or strings that refer to multiple names or indices of columns you wish to operate on
4. Contiguous column or row indices specified by slice notation, as in `x[1:5][2:4]`
5. a colon, `:`, indicating all columns or rows.

Oh and `axis = 1` means you're applying your function row by row, instead column by columns (`axis = 0`):
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that titanic_df is a pandas dataframe. The df[['Age','Sex']] syntax says you that you are applying your function only to the Age and Sex columns of the dataframe. (Selecting a new dataframe that contains only those columns) See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

If you gave titanic_df['Age','Sex'], you would be attempting to select from a multindex. See:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex.

In short, you can't use the second syntax because pandas has that set aside for a different operation.